# Upgrade existing bcrypt hash round count

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I have a database where most of the hashes have a too low round count for our use case. I would like to upgrade these to a higher round/iteration count, hopefully with the [node.bcrypt.js](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js) library.

Example:

I have something like this in my database

```
'$2a$05$Ss068.p/.i4IRzrYoLM/U.ETLpzwrBs2vVfViqgfC5bI4i3BGClZC' 
   //From: bcrypt.hashSync("hello world", 5)
```

And I would like it to become something like this:

```
'$2a$10$6sZOFUEWdVMHoCsgF0k1..RhwoD7VmLlLc5.67/Qw81/XuSuNIOcO'
  //From: bcrypt.hashSync("hello world", 10)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I am thinking the api would probably look something like this:

```
//Non-existing api;
var hash = '$2a$05$Ss068.p/.i4IRzrYoLM/U.ETLpzwrBs2vVfViqgfC5bI4i3BGClZC';
const roundCount = 10
bcrypt.upgradeHashRoundCount(hash, roundCount)
  .then(function(upgradedHash){
    console.log(upgradedHash)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.error("Not a bcrypt hash, or has higher round-count than provided round count")
  })
```

---

Edit for clarification:

I would like to do a batch-job where I fetch all hashes, and do an upgrade on each one, without having the original password available. Since bcrypt essentially just loops around, I think it should in theory be possible to go some more rounds, and store it back.

Comment: Since this API is non-existing, You can make your own function that `can “re-hash” the password after a successful login` or you can `Re-hash all the old hashes with a new hash at once using a batch job`

Comment: The problem is that I want to do a batch-job and actually take existing hashes and upgrade them. This should in theory be possible, but I am not sure how to do it in practice.

Answer (score 7):

Several approaches come to mind. The nice thing about bcrypt is that the rounds are stored in the salt itself and are therefore independent from each other. Means, you can transition smoothly without breaking old passwords.

So two suggestions:

- you could just start using higher salts for all new passwords/passwords that change. The pro is obviously that you just need to up the hash rounds and you are done. Con is that it might take forever until all passwords are stored with the higher rounds.
- You could update the passwords on every successful login if they still have the lower round count. You can use `getRounds(hash)` for that. This way your passwords would get updated very quickly (as soon as they are successfully used once)

Sth like this:

```
function checkPw(pw, user) {
  return bcrypt.compare(pw, user.hash)
  .then(success => {
    if(success && bcrypt.getRounds(hash) < 10) {
      return updateHash(pw, user).then(() => success);
    }
    return success;
  })
}

function updateHash(pw, user) {
  return bcrypt.hash(pw, 10).then((newHash) => {
    user.hash = newHash;
    // update user in db
    return user.save();
  });
}

checkPw('abc', {
  id: 123,
  hash: '$2a$04$7AiVQRTAEPWFwldS7CB6VuQcMSenrPlpoEEGdMyQDE8BxcxcJXPgG'
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually my current approach, but I would have liked to be able to do a batch-job and upgrade the existing passwords so I can be sure all passwords are upgraded, without depending on a new login from all users. We do have inactive users who also should get the upgrade.

Comment: mh, my best guess would be to take a look into the bcypt lib and see how they hash and use that x amount of times on your existing hashes where x would ob. be the difference in rounds (2^10 - 2^5). Not sure if thats exposed by the lib though, so you might want to fork it and add that option yourself

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am by no means a cryptography expert, rather an end-user of bcrypt, so I cannot give any advice if this is cryptographically sound.

I'm currently researching options as we probably also want to change our settings – the two suggestions by Johannes Merz seem the most pragmatic to me, especially of recalculating the hash upon successful login.

Still, we could be faced with the issue you describe - also inactive users should be migrated to a stronger hashing. According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/15959) answer, it is **not** possible to increase the number of rounds only based on a given hash.

What **will** work however is the “hash the hash” approach.

#### Execute these steps within an offline job:

1. Given an existing hash, extract the salt:

   ```
   oldSalt = hashedPassword.substring(0, hashedPassword.lastIndexOf('$') + 23)
   ```

   (the salt is 22 characters long and starts after the last `$`)
2. Hash the existing hash using the new settings (i.e. with a higher number of counts)

   ```
   hashedHashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(hashedPassword, 12)
   ```
3. In your DB, store both, `oldSalt` and `hashedHashedPassword`, and discard `hashedPassword`

#### Execute these steps when users log in:

4. Upon the next login of a user, hash the `suppliedPassword` input using the `oldSalt`, then compare as usual:

   ```
   oldHash = bcrypt.hash(suppliedPassword, oldSalt)
   result = bcrypt.compare(oldHash, hashedHashedPassword)
   ```
5. If `result` is success, get rid of the “double hashing”, by hashing the cleartext password:

   ```
   hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(suppliedPassword)
   ```

   Save `hashedPassword` for the given account and delete `oldSalt` and `hashedHashedPassword`.

Downsides to consider:

- In fact it is still a rolling migration but with the advantage that all your existing hashes will be upgraded at once
- Additional branching logic in the login code which you’ll probably need to keep forever, additional DB columns
- Upgrading the number of rounds again in the future will lead to something like `hashedHashedHashedPassword` + `oldSalt1`, `oldSalt2`, …